# Group csv column data and display count using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am having below data in my csv

```
"Path_Name","Lun_Number","status"
"vmhba0:C2:T0:L1","1","active"
"vmhba0:C1:T0:L1","1","active"
"vmhba1:C0:T7:L230","230","active"
"vmhba1:C0:T7:L231","231","active"
"vmhba1:C0:T7:L232","230","active"
"vmhba1:C0:T7:L235","231","active"
"vmhba1:C0:T7:L236","230","active"
```

I need to group the data based on **Lun_Number** and create a column to get the count of those **Lun_Number**

expected output

```
"Path_Name","Lun_Number","status","Count"
"vmhba0:C2:T0:L1","1","active",    2
"vmhba0:C1:T0:L1","1","active",
"vmhba1:C0:T7:L230","230","active",3
"vmhba1:C0:T7:L231","230","active",
"vmhba1:C0:T7:L232","230","active",
"vmhba1:C0:T7:L235","231","active",2
"vmhba1:C0:T7:L236","231","active",
```

Please let me know how can I do that. I tried `group-object`, `sort-object` but it doesn't seems to be working
Below is the code which is generating the above csv

```
$status_csv = Import-Csv -Path E:\pathstate.csv
$path_csv = Import-Csv -Path E:\PathInfo.csv

foreach($row in $path_csv)
{   
    $path_1 = $row.Path_Name
    $path_2 = $status_csv | where{$_.Name -match "^$path_1$" }
    [PsCustomObject]@{
    Path_Name = $path_1
    Lun_Number = $row.Lun_Number
    status = $path_2.PathState
    } | Export-Csv -Path E:\FinalReport.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append | Group-Object Lun_Number
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see the approach you're trying to take, and I think something like the following could be useful:

```
$path_csv = Import-Csv 'sample.csv'
$Unique_Counts = $path_csv.Lun_Number | Group-Object | Select-Object Name,Count
```

This will help give you the output that you can use as part of your mapping for later, where you can make it dynamic to match with the row you're checking. Which you can use to pull out through a loop, such as *$Unique_Counts*.

Meaning that it you do something like *$Unique_Counts[0].Count*, will be able to grab the Lun_Number associated to it (listed as Name in the array).

```
Name Count
---- -----
1        2
230      3
231      2
```

If you're okay with having the count for each row, you can then use something like what you have:

```
foreach($row in $path_csv)
{   
    $path_1 = $row.Path_Name
    [PsCustomObject]@{
    Path_Name = $path_1
    Lun_Number = $row.Lun_Number 
    status = $row.status
    count = $Unique_Counts | Where-Object {$_.name -eq $row.Lun_Number} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
    } | Export-Csv $finalReport -NoTypeInformation -Append
    
}
```

This then provides me with the following outcome:

```
"Path_Name","Lun_Number","status","count"
"vmhba0:C2:T0:L1","1","active","2"
"vmhba0:C1:T0:L1","1","active","2"
"vmhba1:C0:T7:L230","230","active","3"
"vmhba1:C0:T7:L231","231","active","2"
"vmhba1:C0:T7:L232","230","active","3"
"vmhba1:C0:T7:L235","231","active","2"
"vmhba1:C0:T7:L236","230","active","3"
```

Hope this helps, it may be useful to understand more with the use case, but at least you can grab the unique count for all Lun_numbers. Just has to put it in all rows too.